# Unable to format LocalDate object using camel marshling

Tags: apache-camel

I am saving user object to file using camel routing while saving i am converting user object to json using camel marshaling option.
but while marshaling it is saving date object in following format

```
"birthDate":{"year":2018,"month":"FEBRUARY","era":"CE","dayOfMonth":20,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":51,"leapYear":false,"monthValue":2,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}
```

desired format is

```
  "birthDate":"20-feb-2018"
```

Here is my POJO

```
public class User implements Serializable{

    private String id;

    private String fName;

    private String lName;

    private String email;

    private Integer  pinCode;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    private Boolean isActive;
}
```

And routing url is

```
from("direct:saveUserJson").marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson,User.class).to("file:"+filePath+"?fileName=${exchangeProperty.fileName}");
```

And pom.xml in which i am using camel-jackson-starter and  camel-spring-boot-starter with version 2.20.1

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.igtb</groupId>
    <artifactId>assignment1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>assignment1</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but perhaps it works when you add the shape `String` to your annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```